# How to get only specific rows from database which depend on another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables in the database:

```
users (id, name)
posts (id, user_id, type_id)
user_subscriptions (id, user_id, creator_id, is_paid_subscription) // creator_id references users.id
```

User can subscribe to another user for free, but also user can buy a subscription. `posts.type_id` field controls whether the post is available for all types of subscription or it's available only for users which bought the subscription.

I need to make a query that will return all the posts that are available for current user (if a post is available only for paid subscription, but user subscribed for free then it shouldn't be in result). In other words, it is something like a feed in instagram or facebook, but with paid subscriptions.

So I stuck with this query because I don't understand how to implement this logic with `posts.type_id` field because it depends on `user_subscriptions` table.

Answer (score 0):

So your user has subscriptions that means we need to join the table subscriptions user.id = subscription.user_id
In this table is stated which other user we are subscribed to (creator_id). The information if a post is free or not is stated in the table posts so we also need to join to this table substriptions.creator_id = posts.user_id.

This should do the trick:

```
select posts.*
from users u
inner join user_subscriptions sub on u.id = sub.user_id
inner join posts on sub.creator_id = posts.user_id
where posts.type_id = ? and u.id = ?
```